# What does 肯 mean, in the word 肯定？

Tags: etymology, morphology, semantics, semantic-extensions

肯：

1. Archaic: bone on marrow ----> 中肯=essence
2. Agree, consent
3. Be willing to, be ready to
4. Often, tending to

Which of these meanings gives us the word 肯定？

Comment: Isn't it obvious? "Agree, consent" (it is a fact) --> certain

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me. 肯定 is about a certain probability, not about an agreement between people. Am I missing something?

Comment: 定 in 肯定 means settle; 肯定  = agree to settle (on a fact) = certain

Answer (score 1):

肯 = meat on the bone.
Modern people, do not know this word '肯' meaning

Usually expressed in words, '肯定' and '中肯'

肯定 meaning is sure, definite.

中肯 meaning is middle level definite or Fair determine

中肯 in sentence, 中肯的意見 = appropriate comments

Answer (score 0):

肯定 means positively "sure/certainly", or "definite/confirm". So the answer is "2".